# Why are my images not showing when placed in my functions? Is my function correct?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to get two die images to randomly show a number on the die once the button is clicked.

```js
function SelectImage() {
  var roll = Math.floor(6 * Math.random()) + 1;
  var imgName = 'images/die' + roll + '.gif';
  document.getElementById("dieImg").src = imgName;

  function SelectImage1() {
    var roll1 = Math.floor(6 * Math.random()) + 1;
    var imgName1 = 'images/die' + roll + '.gif';
    document.getElementById("dieImg1").src = imgName1;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Die Rolls</title>
</head>

<body onload="SelectImage();SelectImage1();">

  <p><img id="dieImg" height=7 0 width=7 0><img id="dieImg1" height=7 0 width=7 0></p>

  <input type="button" value="Click to Roll" onclick="SelectImage(); SelectImage1();">

</body>

</html>
```

I expected both images to show the die image and changed to a random number when the button is clicked.

Comment: as revealed more easily by turning your code into a runnable snippet here...you have a syntax error - i.e. a missing bracket at the end of the first function. Did you check your browser's Console for errors?

Comment: After you fix that, the second function tries to use `roll` which is only defined in the first function. You probably meant to say `roll1` there.

Comment: I did but i am very very new to all of this and still learning. I added in the missing bracket but my code won't show the images still and im unsure why it just show the empty boxes.

Comment: did you take into account my second comment as well? Did you check for any further console errors? Did you check if the URLs to your images are actually valid? If you amend the code according to my two suggestions it will cause the img src properties to be populated correctly when you click the button...but that's not the same as it actually being able to load those images from the server.

Comment: I fixed it, I accidently placed a period randomly. thank you for your help!!

Answer (score -1):

Hm adding the missing brace might help a lot ;)

```
function SelectImage() {
    var roll = Math.floor(6 * Math.random()) + 1;
    var imgName = 'images/die' + roll + '.gif';
    document.getElementById("dieImg").src = imgName;
} //  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

function SelectImage1() {
    var roll1 = Math.floor(6 * Math.random()) + 1;
    var imgName1 = 'images/die' + roll + '.gif';
    document.getElementById("dieImg1").src = imgName1;
}
```

Comment: This code still won't execute. You missed the other, logical, error. It's all been sorted long before anyway..just some typos - see the comments above. The post should really be closed as having a typographical error rather than needing an answer.

Comment: This code will execute if he has the images in the right place and the right names. Which has to match the name he generates. I didnt check his math formula in detail, but that does not look that odd and its easy to track down by console.log. I do not know why he uses 2 functions, i would write one with just one parameter to select the image but.. I just can imagine that the image path is wrong. Usually the things are a bit more sorted in the directory- So "../images/  instead "images/. But hey...

Comment: "This code will execute"...no, it won't. See the comments above. Clue: the problem is the `roll` variable in the second function. You could try this yourself trivially using a StackSnippet or JSFiddle or something - test rather than guess, before answering. Anyway, as OP says in the comments, it was already solved and sorted before you even posted.

Comment: P.S. I agree the code is clunky and repetitive but that isn't the topic of the question. There is a CodeReview StackExchange site where people can ask about that kind of thing.